# Under FreeBSD, can a VLAN interface have a smaller MTU than the primary interface?

Tags: networking, freebsd, vlan, mtu, lacp

I have a system with two physical interfaces, combined into a LACP
aggregation group.  That LACP channel has two VLANs, one untagged (the
"native vlan") and one using VLAN tagging.  This gives us:

```
lagg0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=19b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4>
        ether 00:25:90:1d:fe:8e
        inet 10.243.24.23 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.243.24.255
        media: Ethernet autoselect
        status: active
        laggproto lacp
        laggport: em1 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
        laggport: em0 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
vlan0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
        ether 00:25:90:1d:fe:8e
        inet 10.243.16.23 netmask 0xffffff80 broadcast 10.243.16.127
        media: Ethernet autoselect
        status: active
        vlan: 610 parent interface: lagg0
```

Is it possible to set a 9K MTU on `lagg0` while preserving the 1500
byte MTU on `vlan0`?  Normally I would simply try this out, but this
is actually on a vendor-supported platform and I am loathe to make
changes "behind the back" of their administration interface.

This system is roughly FreeBSD 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. The VLAN parent must be equal to or larger MTU than the VLAN itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used different MTUs vor vlan and parent Interface in FreeBSD 4.x times (1496 and 1500 in my case), so i think it should work.

You could just use two FreeBSD machines connected to each other and try it out.